# How to handle JSON body using Tornado w/ python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, tornado

Tornado 4.5.2 using Python3 represents the request body as a byte object instead of a native dictionary.  This presents a problem for methods like `RequestHandler.get_body_argument()` which will not access the field correctly.

My question is how to correctly have tornado parse these bodies into more useable dictionaries so the standard library will work.  I've looked throughout tornado's documentation and there's next to nothing on even the existence of this problem.

Am I missing something here or will I need to re-implement those methods myself?

Answer (score 2):

Tornado never automatically parses JSON; it only automatically parses HTML-standard form encoding (the data models of form encoding and JSON are different, so it wouldn't make sense to use the same family of `get_argument`/`get_arguments` methods in the less-ambiguous JSON format). If you want to handle JSON requests, it's one line to parse it yourself:

```
args = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

Comment: This answer might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348861/122033